# Completeness of infinitely intersecting causal geodesics in strongly causal spacetimes

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, general-relativity, geodesics, semi-riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a connected, smooth, strongly causal Lorentzian manifold, and consider an inextendible causal geodesic $\sigma : [0,b) \to M$ (a priori, $b$ may be $\infty$) with the following property:

For every sequence $(s_n)_{n=1}^\infty \subset [0,b)$ such that $s_n \to b$, there exists a subsequence $(s_{n_k})$ and an inextendible, **incomplete** causal geodesic $\gamma:[0,1) \to M$ such that there's a sequence $(t_k) \subset [0,1)$ with $t_k \to 1$ and $\sigma(s_{n_k}) = \gamma(t_k)$. In words: given any sequence whatsoever along the end of $\sigma$, there's an incomplete causal geodesic that intersects $\sigma$ infinitely many times along some subsequence.

**Question:** Must $\sigma$ be incomplete, i.e. must $b$ be finite?

**Notes**:

Of course, if $\sigma$ is incomplete, the property is satisfied trivially by taking $\gamma$ to be the appropriate reparameterization of $\sigma$.

*Inextendible* here means that $\displaystyle \lim_{s \to b} \sigma(s)$ does not exist (and similarly for $\gamma$), so that $\sigma$ cannot be future-extended as continuous curve (or, equivalently, as a smooth geodesic).

While I'm not sure if the causality and inextendibility conditions are necessary for the result, it's a standard result that together they imply that $\sigma(s_n)$ can never converge, and hence that the image of $\sigma$ is closed, and further that $\sigma$ eventually exits and remains outside of any compact set (similarly for $\gamma$).

My intuition is that the answer is positive, but I'm not sure how to go about a proof-- it seems one would want to somehow bound the parameter of $\sigma$ in terms of that of some $\gamma$.

If absolutely necessary, I would also be interested if this could be proven under the stronger hypothesis that $\sigma$ and $\gamma$ are timelike, or if the spacetime were assumed globally hyperbolic.

Though I've come upon this problem in an academic research context (attempting to prove properties of a proposed alternative characterization of black holes), I originally [posted this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4294598/355036) to MSE in hopes it might have a somewhat elementary resolution. It's had no answers after over week, so I've decided to try asking here. My impression is that this is appropriate, but please advise if not.